# Is it possible to add hardware on a remote machine and use it as if it was installed on the local machine?

Tags: windows, remote-access, sound-card

We have two computers in the apartment running Windows 7 and Windows Vista. 99% of the time we use headphones but every now and then we have a desire for some ambiance so we got a set of 2.1 speakers. But now only one of us has access to the speakers unless we move them around every now and then.

So I was wondering if it's possible to add the other computer's sound card as a hardware device on my computer so that I can configure, for instance, Winamp to play through the other computer's sound card, hence the speakers connected to the other computer.

Answer (score 1):

There are various remote control options which would allow you to control actions on one machine from the other.  An RDP server is available on the Windows versions above the Home editions.  This allows you to login to the other system, and use it as if you were in front of the screen.

For your purposes installing a VNC server might work better.   It would allow you to share the desktop, and control the music player.   You can disconnect once you have the music playing.

I haven't investigated the various stream casting solutions, but that might work as well.  You would set the computer with speakers to play a stream generated by other system. Winamp may have a solution.

There might also be a remote control solution for your media player. Or you might find another that allows remote control.